# Is it possible to swap out nearly identical classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, metaprogramming

```
class Parent
 def punish!
 end
end

class Mom < Parent
end

class Dad < Parent
end
```

If I have an instance of `Dad` but want to make it an instance of `Mom`, is this possible in Ruby?

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: @13aal because Mom and Dad might have their own sets of methods and attributes perhaps. How does Mom become Dad?

Comment: when you swap out? how exactly do you mean? Do you mean if you have A mom object, can you do something to it, to make it a dad?

Comment: Well think about it like this. You have a Mom and Dad that are both parents, so in programming they're both inherited from the parent class. If you're worried about it you could just make one class inherited from the parent class and call it `MomAndDad` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "swap" you mean substitute in the context of a variable:

```
parent = Mom.new
parent.punish!

parent = Dad.new
parent.punish!
```

You can reassign a variable at any time. What you can't do is pervert an instance of object from one class into another. Once created it's basically stuck in that class.

The same principle here applies to object attributes and other places where an object reference might be saved.

Comment: >What you can't do is pervert an instance of object from one class into another. 
This is what I wanted. dang!

Comment: It goes against most object-oriented design patterns. There are ways of making an object specialize and take on new behaviour after it has been created if that's what you need, or you can write a `Dad.to_mom` method that emits a Mom-version of same.

Comment: What you need is a Parent class that both Mom and Dad inherit from. Then any objects that expect a Parent will accept either a Mom or a Dad. See: Polymorphism...

Comment: @AndyJones That doesn't help with switching an object from one type to another.

Comment: @tadman -- well, yes, the point is you don't switch an object from type A to type B.  You design a system that will accept type A or B interchangably. If you can do that you get the same functionality as switching A to B...

Comment: @AndyJones This is specifically about changing types. Using a parent class won't give you methods only available in the subclasses.

Comment: @tadman -- if your two classes have the same parent, then you can pass either, and you CAN use methods only available in one, so long as you test using `respond_to?` or `kind_of?` -- which given duck-typing, you should arguably be doing anyway...

Comment: @AndyJones Please re-read the question because while correct you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @tadman Which is it -- am I correct, or barking up the wrong tree? I can't be both. In any case I think we can both agree that this conversation does nothing to help anyone reading SO?

Comment: @AndyJones You're technically correct, but that fact isn't relevant to this question. Please read the question more closely.